# How do I get Vimwiki to display brackets and not generate a link

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

I am currently keeping notes on Bash programming. Now the shortcut for the "test" function often used to constructing conditional statements is [[ ]].

I just began using Vimwiki and imported a note document and it changed all the "test" function calls into links, eg, [[ ${counter} -gt 9 ]] --> "*${counter}*-gt_9_" (without the quotes).

I searched for the answer and could not find anything. Maybe I'm phrasing the question incorrectly, though. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use back ticks to solve this issue.

#### Just surround your code inside the back ticks for single line, like so:

`[[ ${counter} -gt 9 ]]`

#### Use triple back ticks for multi line:

```

[[ ${counter} -gt 9 ]]

```

Comment: Sorry for never responding to you're comment... thanks it solved the issue :)